# Recommended to vs recommended for

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Should I write

> "This is recommended **to** people who like cheap but highly useful stuff"

or

> "This is recommended **for** people who like cheap but highly useful stuff"?

Comment: Both are grammatical and make sense. Usage depends on the subtle difference in meaning. IOW, they don't mean quite the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

**recommend(ed) for** is defined as, according to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/recommend+for):

> **to suggest someone for something.**
>
> *I would be very glad to recommend you for promotion.*

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/recommend+to) also defines **recommend(ed) to** as:

> **to suggest that someone choose someone or something.**
>
> *I would like to recommend Sally to you as a good prospect for
> membership on the committee.*
>
> *Could you recommend a good mechanic to me?*

The distinction between the two was outlined by a superuser who goes by the name of Califjim in [this thread](https://www.englishforums.com/English/RecoommendRecommendTo/xbkhc/post.htm) on EnglishForums.com, which reads as follows:

> No preposition when recommending a person or thing to someone else.
>
> **to** goes with the person to whom the recommendation is addressed.
>
> **for** goes with the position for which the person is recommended.

In simpler terms, you **recommend** *something* **to** a *person*, and **recommend** *someone* **for** *a position, or a job*.

Answer (score 0):

In the first you are recommending it more directly to the addressees. The second does not have to be addressed to the group; it's just claimed to be something they would like.

For instance normally *you wouldn't recommend dog-food **to** a dog*.
But you could tell its owner that *this dog-food is recommended **for** all kinds of dogs*.